# Can we call an anonymous function without storing it in a variable in PHP?

Tags: php, anonymous-function

In Javascript, it's easy to call a function returned by another function in one single statement. Consider for example:

```
function createOperation(operator)
{
    return Function("a", "b", "return a " + operator + "b;")
}

var result = createOperation("*")(2, 3);
```

Here, we call a function to create another function that multiplies two values, then call this new function with two arguments.

If I try to replicate a similar code snippet in PHP, I end up using two statements and one extra variable:

```
function createOperation(operator)
{
    return create_function('$a,$b', 'return $a '.$operator.' $b;');
}

$temp_var = createOperation("+");
$result = $temp_var(2, 3);
```

The short, Javascript-like form doesn't work:

```
$result = createOperation("+")(2, 3);
```

This is especially tedious when writing an invocation chain (pseudocode):

```
foo(arg1)(arg2, arg3)()(...)
```

Which would become:

```
$temp1 = foo($arg1);
$temp2 = $temp1($arg2, $arg3);
$temp3 = $temp2();
...
```

So my question is: is there a way in PHP to call a function returned by another function without using temporary variables, or at least in one single same statement?

Comment: Why would you do it like that? There is absolutely no reason against `function createOperation($operator, $a, $b) {`.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I concur. Pass the arguments required initially to the parent function.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois That's just sample code to show the problem. I thought that would be clear.

Comment: Have you tried `$result = {createOperation("+")}(2, 3);` or `$result = (createOperation("+"))(2, 3);`? These are guesses, haven't tried them myself.

Comment: wouldn't that be useful to create a scripting API/Framework/Library? Where the user would provide basic code or even custom code with parameters then the API/... would parse the code and create a valid PHP code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen in php repo, @NikiC is actively working on implementing [his RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/uniform_variable_syntax), the `()()` syntax is already in the trunk:

https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/64e4c9eff16b082f87e94fc02ec620b85124197d

I don't know what the release map looks like, hope we'll get decent syntax in php very soon.